# Google Maps в Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Хочу добавить с существующий проект карту, сгенерировала ключ, добавила в Манифест, сделала rebuild project, дальше во всех тьюториалах написано, что нужно создать xml такого типа:

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Когда добавляю эту xml, то Android Studio не видит `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"` и подчеркивает эту строчку красным. Вопрос, что-то еще где-то нужно импортировать? Или этот `name` ни на что не влияет? и его можно заменить/убрать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скачала `Google play services` в SDK Manager, еще быстрый способ добавить карты в существующий проект, `File -> New -> Google ->Google Maps Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

Импортировать весь Google Play services:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
```

Или можно по мере надобности, для карт достаточно:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

И Вам нужно добавить фрагмент так

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

плюс как писали ниже добавьте

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
```